# Trim text after Bracket in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, listobject, excel-tables

I would like to trim off the text which is after the bracket in the cell Value

The current formula I'm using keeps giving me the error not being able to extract the targetted string.

```
=LEFT([@[Name ]],FIND("(",[@[Name ]]))
```

> I want to go shopping (Today)

Goal: Is to remove

> (Today)

Expected Result:

> I want to go shopping

Comment: @pnuts i have rephrased the thread

Comment: `=LEFT([@Name],FIND("(*",[@Name]))`

I have tried it is not working and comes with the error #value

Comment: what about using formula?

Answer (score 2):

One of these should do.

```
=TRIM(LEFT([name], FIND("(", [name]&"(")-1))
=TRIM(REPLACE([name], FIND("(", [name]&"("), LEN([name]), TEXT(,)))
```

Note that I suffixed the original text with the character that the FIND is looking for. In this manner, it will always be found even if it is not in the original text.

You may find that you have a rogue trailing space in the Name header label.

[image]